# Video resources for learning to use ASP.NET with a database

Tags: asp.net, database

**Can you recommend any good video resources for learning to use ASP.NET with a database?** I come from a PHP/MySQL background and it seems that Visual Studio does too much magic for me to wrap my head around using written material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/learn/

You can find videos that walk you through pretty much anything here.  By the time you exhaust the videos, you'll be familliar enough with .Net to feel comfortable using the MSDN Library at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd566231(VS.100).aspx

Comment: How come I never saw that site before. If anyone else is looking, the very basic database stuff is scattered under the "General ASP.NET". That should be enough to get anyone started. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found Dimecasts particularly useful to learn about asp.net

http://dimecasts.net/

Comment: +1. Good link! Not the kind of stuff you get from the asp.net site...  This looks like a great supplemental learning resource.

Comment: Yep I've used it quite often.. it covers quite a lot of useful topics especially mvc and iocs :) plust they are quite short as well - nice bite size!!

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at Microsoft Learning's [Ramp up](http://www.myrampup.com) area, especially the "[Learn ASP.NET: for PHP developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/dd861537.aspx)" track, which in in addition to telling you about ASP.NET's way of working, also compares this with PHP usage.